# Decoupling date pattern in file name and rolling frequency

Tags: java, logback

I am using logback and I have this in the file-name pattern for TimeBasedRollingPolicy

weekly-perf-summaries-%d{yyyy-WW}.csv

This would roll the files at the first day of each week,which is what I intend to do.
But it would also name the file as weekly-perf-summaries-2012-02.csv,considering we are in the second week of the month.
The requirement is to name the file with current date i.e weekly-perf-summaries-2012-04-16.csv.
Is it possible to specify different rolling frequency and a different date pattern in file name.

Answer (score 0):

As of logback 1.0.1, it is possible to specify multiple %d tokens but only one of which can be primary, i.e. used to infer the rollover period. All other tokens must be marked as auxiliary by passing the 'aux' parameter. See "[fileNamePattern](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#TimeBasedRollingPolicy)" in the docs.

In your case, you could write:

```
%d{yyyy-WW}/weekly-perf-summaries-%d{yyyy-MM-dd, aux}.csv
```

In the above example, files will be created in directories denoted by the primary date tokens, by year and week. Currently, there is no way for the primary date token to be silent.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.But if we do not need different directories for each week, I think a custom file appender has to be created.